# Hotwire turbolinks and problem with event listeners

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbolinks, hotwire-rails

Hi I have a problem with event listener, I am using turbolinks my listener looks like:
`document.addEventListener("turbolinks:load", ...`
when I for the first time  visit the page i get in browser console this error:
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'children' of null`. After reloading everything is working properly. I guess that this is the problem with asynchronicity but i don't know how to solve that in wise way.

Comment: what is the problem you're trying to solve with your event listener? it is entirely possible that there's another way that avoids this error.

Comment: I use event listener to switch classes in css after clicking on selected divs and some things are not loaded for the first time I visit the site due to asynchronicity.

Comment: I would highly recommend using Stimulus for your Javascript needs here. Stimulus is meant to work with Hotwire. This doesn't answer your question exactly, but if you ask a new question about changing CSS on click with Hotwire/Turbo/Stimulus I can provide a sample. See: https://stimulus.hotwire.dev/

Comment: Ok thanks I wiil try stimulus then :)